# C++ namespace FW ; Matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia

I'm trying to implement some basic matrix multiplication, for translation.
In my opinion the multiplication should work, but I get this error.

> binary '*=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'FW::Vec4f' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Here is my code, using std and FW namepsace

```
    Mat4f World;

float x, y, z;

World.setCol(0, Vec4f(1, 0, 0, x));
World.setCol(1, Vec4f(0, 1, 0, y));
World.setCol(2, Vec4f(0, 0, 1, z));
World.setCol(3, Vec4f(0, 0, 0, 1));

World *= Vec4f(translation_, 1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Mat4f seems not to provide the operator, see http://globalempiresoft.com/tools/AR/OpenVRML/openvrml-0.18.6/doc/manual/structopenvrml_1_1mat4f.html

Answer (score 1):

The result of the multiplication of a matrix with a vector is a vector (not a matrix). So this

```
World *= Vec4f(translation_, 1, 1, 1);
```

makes no sense. That would be more like it

```
Vec4f r = World * Vec4f(translation_, 1,1,1);
```

My suggestion: Get your linear algebra polished up.